# How to use multiple strings as list keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to join multiple variables as a list() key

```
H = list()
a = "hi"
b = "bye"
H[a+b] = 12
print(H["hibye"])
```

but I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` and I want it to print `12`.

I also want to know if this can be done with `Counter` or other types of dictionaries.

Comment: This will work for a `dict`, not a `list` (as the error says, lists can't have string indexes); just use `H = dict()` instead

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "use as a list key". Lists do not have keys. They have *indices*, and you don't get to choose which ones are valid - only integers may be used, and the valid values depend on how many items are in the list. That's the purpose of the list: to store a *sequence* of values, such that each value has a defined *position*. "i also want to know if this can be done with Counter() or other types of Dictionaries" Yes, it can be done with any kind of dictionary - more generally, any kind of `Mapping`.

Comment: To understand this sort of thing properly and in detail, I recommend that you follow a Python tutorial in order. The official Python documentation includes one.

Answer (score 1):

Lists don't have text-based keys.  They only have items in them referenced by an integer index.  For example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(my_list[0])
```

This will print 'a' because 'a' is in the 0 position (1st) position of the list.

A dictionary on the other hand users key/value pairs for storage.  For example:

```
mydict = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
print(mydict["key1"])
```

This will print "value1" because the value represented by the key "key1" in the dictionary is "value1"

Comment: Thank you! Can i use "mydict[0]" to print "value1" as in the list?

Comment: You can do: mydict[list(mydict.keys())[0]]